# HTML Content and watermarks

Tags: html, css, image

Is it possible to watermark or otherwise secure HTML content so it can be printed but not photocopied after it's printed?  For an application that prints passes, for example.

Comment: Do you have control on paper and ink used ? Then you have your answer.

Comment: More information is needed, but I'll say no. The only thing is requiring the pass to be printed on a certain color of paper, and the contrast is just high enough to read but looks bad on b&w

Answer (score 1):

This is way beyond HTML/CSS's capabilities.  If you watermark an image then it will have to show up on the printed copy to be visible in a photocopied version, unless you are using a very sophisticated printer.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is simply not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a special print layout which simply hides the hole page:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
* {display:none;}
</style>
```

Or try `html` instad of `*` not sure if older IE versions support the asterisk.